# Вопрос с блокировкой скриншота в приложении

Tags: java

Вопрос таков, я взял готовую форму с GitHab
Вот ссылка: https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form
Но суть в том что при добавлении этой формы блокируется возможность делать скрин, есть ли возможность это отключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможность делать скриншот явно запрещена в библиотеке путём установки флага `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE` [тут](https://github.com/braintree/android-card-form/blob/8110aed47407d75cb68c5e2a041cf2191dbeee2b/CardForm/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/cardform/view/CardForm.java#L283)

Отключить можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70986396/3212712) (сразу после инициализации вьюхи библиотеки, т.е. после вызова метода `setup`):

```
activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, код который вы предоставили не совсем верный либо же я его не так использовал, я пошел немного другой дорогой и прописал вот так после setup (Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);)

Comment: Пожалуйста) Под `activity` имелся в виду экземпляр активити, ссылку на который можно по разному получить в разных контекстах. У вас, получается, код был в активити написан, засим да, надо `activity` на `this` заменить (или вообще не писать).